# ionic 3: Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I created ionic 3 project template 'tabs' using `ionic start ionTutorial tabs` (tabs which were generated: home/about/contact)

Then I added my own tabs using
ionic g page  (tabs: project/notifications/settings).
Then I deleted `home about` and `contact` folders from /src/pages

I updated files:
`tabs.html` (there were changed `tabTitle` and `tabIcon` only) and
tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ProjectPage } from '../project/project';
import { NotificationsPage } from '../notifications/notifications';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings';

@Component({...})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = ProjectPage;
  tab2Root = NotificationsPage;
  tab3Root = SettingsPage;
  constructor() { }
}
```

and app.module.ts

```
//this was updated (3x import)
import { ProjectPage } from '../pages/project/project';
import { NotificationsPage } from '../pages/notifications/notifications';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ProjectPage,       //this was updated
    NotificationsPage, //this was updated
    SettingsPage,      //this was updated
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ProjectPage,       //this was updated
    NotificationsPage, //this was updated
    SettingsPage,      //this was updated
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I received an error
Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'**\src\pages\about\about.ts'**

After that I closed web browser and I tried to run `ionic serve` again and here are results

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
watch started ...
build dev started ...
```

and the command line 'is back'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the solution was to remove all files from www/build folder and restart dev server. The app is working fine now.